# Trouble hidding div with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having some trouble with my javascript as my coding skills are well below par. I am trying to create a simple pop up box (which I can sort of do) but I am unable to close this box. I have some code written, it was pasted from previous work and edited a bit, I know its rough but I'm a real novice at JS. Heres my JSFiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/4v4txoxs/2/
`thanks`

```
$('.up').click(function () {
    var Show = $('.Show');

    if (Show.hasClass('visible')) {
        $('.PopUp').animate({
            "opacity": "0"
        }, "fast");
        $('.PopUp').animate({
            "z-index": "2"
        }, "fast");
    } else {
        $('.PopUp').animate({
            "opacity": "1"
        }, "fast");
        $('.PopUp').animate({
            "z-index": "5"
        }, "fast");
    }
});
```

Comment: That's because when you made it visible, you forgot to add the class visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show and hide the class *visible*, You can achieve it using [`$.fn.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

```
//Added the line before if block
Show.toggleClass('visible');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/k6bak6oL/)

Comment: Thanks a million, not sure why this question got down voted but oh well.